# Menu -> submenu -> submenu in Slide drawer menu if it is possible or not in android?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am trying to create a slide drawer menu with this format `Menu->submenu->submenu` in android but it's not working, if it possible means also I need how to set the final submenu onclick event.

Please help me any one I need this and surfing this over a month but still not getting any conclusion.

Please give me some ideas about this concepts

Code :

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    //private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    public static int cart;
    static boolean read=true;
    InputStream is=null;
    String result=null;
    String line=null;
    String mail_id;
    int code;
    static boolean changebackground=true;
    //expandable listview
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView mDrawerList;;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    //expandable listview
    TextView totalitems;
    DatabaseHandler data;
    ImageView gotocart;
    List<String> OurTemplates;
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        changebackground=false;




        final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.actionbar,
                null);

 ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        // Set up your ActionBar
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

actionBarLayout.setLayoutParams(lp);

       Button menu=(Button) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.menu);

     totalitems=(TextView) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.detail_totalcartitem);
        data=new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());



        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    //  mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        mDrawerList.setGroupIndicator(null);
     prepareListData();
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1), true, ""));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1)));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1)));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();



        //expandable listview






        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        mDrawerList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        mDrawerList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            /*  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                /
                int pos=childPosition;
                listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
                listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
                changebackground=true;

                if(pos==0)
                {
                // Adding child data
                listDataHeader.add("E-commerce Templates");


                // Adding child data
                List<String> E_commerce = new ArrayList<String>();
                E_commerce.add("Cs-Cart");
                E_commerce.add("Magento");
                E_commerce.add("Opencart");
                E_commerce.add("Prestashop");
                E_commerce.add("Abantecart");
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), E_commerce); 

                listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

                // setting list adapter
                mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                mDrawerList.expandGroup(0, true);
                }
                else if(pos==1)
                {
                    listDataHeader.add("CMS Templates");
                    List<String> CMS = new ArrayList<String>();
                    CMS.add("Wordpress");
                    CMS.add("Drupal");
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), CMS); 
                    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                    mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    mDrawerList.expandGroup(0, true);
                }
                else if(pos==2)
                {
                    listDataHeader.add("Video Sharing Templates");
                    List<String> video_sharing = new ArrayList<String>();
                    video_sharing.add("Clipshare");
                    video_sharing.add("Phpmotion");
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), video_sharing); 
                    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                    mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    mDrawerList.expandGroup(0, true);
                }
                else if(pos==3)
                {
                    listDataHeader.add("Social Networking Templates");
                    List<String> social_networking = new ArrayList<String>();
                    social_networking.add("Dolphin");
                    social_networking.add("Socialengine");
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), social_networking); 
                    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                    mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    mDrawerList.expandGroup(0, true);
                }
                else if(pos==4)
                {
                    listDataHeader.add("Free Templates");
                    List<String> free_templates = new ArrayList<String>();
                    free_templates.add("Cs-Cart");
                    free_templates.add("Magento");
                    free_templates.add("Opencart");
                    free_templates.add("Prestashop");
                    free_templates.add("Dolphine");
                    free_templates.add("Drupal");
                    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), free_templates); 
                    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
                    mDrawerList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    mDrawerList.expandGroup(0, true);
                }


                return false;
            }
        });





        ;

menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);

                }
                else if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);


                }

            }
        });

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name 
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle("E-commerce Templates");
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            displayView(0);
        }




    }


    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void displayView(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //fragment = new Home();
            // click();

            ///mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            break;
        case 1:
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, CsCart.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case 2:
             click();
            break;
        case 3:
             click();
            break;
        case 4:
             click();
            break;
        case 5:
             click();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }



    void click()
    {

        navDrawerItems.clear();


    }


    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Home");
        listDataHeader.add("Our Templates");
        listDataHeader.add("Our Services");
        listDataHeader.add("Portfolio");
        listDataHeader.add("Add-ons");
        listDataHeader.add("Blog");
        listDataHeader.add("Forum");
        listDataHeader.add("Contact us");


        // Adding child data
        OurTemplates = new ArrayList<String>();
        OurTemplates.add("E-commerce Templates");
        OurTemplates.add("CMS Templates");
        OurTemplates.add("Video Sharing Templates");
        OurTemplates.add("Social Networking Templates");
        OurTemplates.add("Free Templates");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0),new ArrayList<String>() );
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), OurTemplates);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), new ArrayList<String>());
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), new ArrayList<String>());
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), new ArrayList<String>());
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), new ArrayList<String>());
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), new ArrayList<String>());
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(7), new ArrayList<String>());// Header, Child data

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## My personal experience

When I first learned Android, I thought it was great because it was so easy. You could find an answer online for virtually any issue you were having.

Now, I couldn't feel differently. Because we are writing a complex engineering tool in Android at my workplace, we have to do a lot of custom UI programming. It's not fun. It's a layer of hell. Android is a pain to do custom coding for.

Now, that being said. I would advocate that you stick with the [current Android standard](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html). After that, you have some options. Here are two example of what we did:

1. 'About' - At the top of the page, we have a small fragment with a spinner with sub-menu items. These include 'About Us' 'Changelog' 'Privacy Policy' etc.
2. 'Help' - The entire page is filled with a Listview of all the sub-menu items (one for each of our help topics). When you click a topic, it opens a new fragment that shows 'previous' and 'next' buttons for the surrounding topics.

Explore your options. If you've been searching for months for this one solution, it might be time to be flexible with your desires.

## Find a better way to organize your information

Keep in mind that (depending on how you implement it), navigating complex menus can be complicated and disorienting. Try to make this as easy for the user as possible by having as few levels as possible. Check out this website that shows [different ways to organize complex navigation on a web page](http://bradfrost.com/blog/web/complex-navigation-patterns-for-responsive-design/). You may get some ideas to implement on mobile. *(Hint: Listviews allow you to have non-clickable headings as items…)* Here is an example of an app with [one sub-menu](http://www.astekweb.com/ux/muse-ability-complex-menus-go-mobile/). Do some more research so you know exactly what you would like to implement and how. Then…

## Write a Custom Control

One thing Android does right is that they actually do give helpful documentation: [Creating Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html). You can extend the DrawerLayout control to handle multiple list views, or basically whatever you would like.

Good luck!